# What is the difference between Alfresco Community Edition and Alfresco Enterprise Edition?

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco

What is the difference between Alfresco Community Edition and Alfresco Enterprise Edition ?

1. Any differences in both features it provides ?
2. Can we down load Enterprise edition with longer trial license ?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150591/using-alfresco-community-in-production

Answer (score 10):

The Enterprise Edition is the commercially supported Edition. In addition to support, you also get patches, updates, indemnity, and access to certified partners. From a functionality standpoint, the software is virtually the same. There are a few things only available to Enterprise such as support for commercial databases and application servers, the XAM connector, and JMX.

Both Enterprise and Community are tested by our QA team. When it is time to distribute an Enterprise release, a branch is created. That branch undergoes additional testing and is frequently patched with fixes. These fixes go into the Enterprise release for that branch and are later merged back into the main code line so that they will be available in a future Community release.

Both Enterprise and Community are 100% open source. Community is distributed under the LGPLv3 license.

If you start an Enterprise Trial and you need to extend beyond your 30 day license you should talk to the account rep you are working with. Extensions can be granted.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, as of the 4.1 releases, HA & clustering is no longer supported at all in the community.  Research the forums and you will see that enterprise is the only way to go for enterprise deployments.

Answer (score 1):

They [say](http://www.alfresco.com/products/)

> 1. Alfresco Enterprise Edition includes Document Management, Web Content Management, Share and the Content Platform. Records Management, as well as Enterprise add-ons such as clustering and a connector for content addressable storage can be added as an additional subscription on top of the base subscription.
> 2. Contact us to learn more about pricing for our Alfresco Enterprise Subscription.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Do you mean Community edition will not suports to the features of document management webcontent management and webcontent management ?Please clarify ?

Comment: It certainly sounds like that. All these features have links to their own pages where you can get quotes and sign up for a 30 day trial. Maybe someone else can answer more comprehensively here, but you should probably read up on their web site and maybe contact their sales rep.

Answer (score 1):

thats wrong! the addons such as clustering are included in the community release. the difference is, that the enterprise version is the stable version with support and extensive tests

see: http://storage.pardot.com/1234/46851/Alfresco_Datasheet_Community_Network_eng.pdf

"No High-Availability Cluster Testing"

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the Community Edition is generally sufficient to serve about 50 concurrent users. This should be good enough for most usage scenarios. The Community Edition has all the core features that the Enterprise Edition has. The only difference is, you do not get official technical support for the Community Edition from the company. However, Alfresco has a strong users community base that provides assistance when needed.

You can try Alfresco Community Edition by subscribing to hosted services offered at http://www.alfresco-fusion.com

After signing up you will be offered fully functional Alfresco Server at a very affordable monthly cost.

Comment: Are you affiliated with that hosting company?